# Ktor Server. How to add swagger-ui like spring doc-openapi-util?

Tags: kotlin, swagger-ui, openai-api, ktor

I development http API on Ktor and want to add swagger-ui and swagger generator. I used to use Spring and Spring Boot and I just added dependency for doc-openapi-util and and everything worked!

How to do this fo work Ktor?

I have tested ktor-server-openapi and ktor-server-swagger, but it doesn't work the way I want it to. I want to fully automate these operations for swagger/openapi as in doc-openapi-util.

Comment: Have you followed the official [setup documentation](https://ktor.io/docs/openapi.html)? It lists all steps required to get your OpenAPI spec generated and published.

Comment: This requires already having an existing file such as swagger.yaml (in the documentation documentation.yaml), that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately, the generation of OpenAPI specification is supported only by the Ktor IDEA plugin, which is bundled with The IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.

Comment: I have a personal license for Idea Ultimate, and I generate OpenAPI spec manually also for change my API. But, I want automated this Process!!! It work for Spring Boot with doc-openapi-util plugin. Just add dependency doc-openapi-util and everything works by itself !

Comment: There is a pending feature request for this https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-324927